# Looking for a decent iOS 5 development tutorial

Tags: xcode, ios5, mobile

I'm just starting out with iPhone development. I started with Stanford's recent tutorial, and while it's up to date, the project it's using in the demo is extremely boring to code (a calculator? really?).

So I'm looking for a different tutorial now. Been searching for days but all I found were outdated books and videos. I need something that teaches me with all the new API's and skips memory management and obsolete stuff.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory management is not obsolete by any means. Automatic Reference Counting helps but you still need to learn how retain/release works in order to avoid certain pitfalls. iOS does *not* provide garbage collection and even with ARC you are still responsible for managing your memory.

[This is the best book on the subject I know of.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773772) It is a very clear example of where $30 invested in a few hundred pages is vastly more cost-effective than an infinity of free stuff on the internet.

There is also [Ray Wenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com/) for specific tutorials.

Comment: +1 for Ray Wenderlich. Great tutorials.

Comment: Thanks alot Tim. But aren't there new stuff in xcode 4.2 that makes development much easier that these books won't explain?

Comment: @KeyStroke there's two things to learn here: the language (and concepts, core APIs, all that stuff) and the tools (Xcode, clang, Interface Builder, Instruments.) The first one is orders of magnitude more important than the second and, without it, no amount of expertise on the tools will help. I promise that you won't miss out by reading that book and working through the exercises using your copy of Xcode 4. When you've done that it'll take you perhaps a day to get up to speed on the new stuff: ARC, Storyboards and some domain-specific APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. I'll always be grateful for your help.